# Uncertainty in gradient of data

Tags: regression, error, uncertainty

So I have a set of 9 x,y values, and I need to find the gradient/slope of the data, AND its associated error.

Without the error, I would've used Excels LINEST function, but as the errors in my y values are large (no x value errors) I need LINEST to take these into account.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're prepared to assume a Gaussian distribution of the errors, you're looking for a standard error / confidence interval for the slope coefficient in simple linear regression. There are many sources, e.g. [Kerns (2011), *Introduction to Probability & Statistics using R*, Ch.11.2.4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IPSUR/vignettes/IPSUR.pdf).

Comment: Assuming the slope is $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ & not the other way around.

Comment: The online [LINEST help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/linest-function-HP010069838.aspx) explains how to extract this information (and more).  For instance, the standard error of the slope will be in row 2, column 1 of the LINEST output.  Could you please edit your question to tell us *how* you want to "take these into account"?

Comment: I have since solved this, linest only computes standard error, doesn't take into account the errors on the raw data. To solve this I did a weighted least square regression.